# Nginx config to serve an Angular app under an URI prefix where files are generated in the same folder as "index.html"

Tags: angular, nginx

There are a lot of Angular/Nginx examples on the web but I'm still unable to make my config work. I use Angular 13.

In `angular.json`:

- `outputPath` is "`www`"
- `baseHref` is "`/my-project/`"

and for the assets:

```
"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "src/assets",
    "output": "assets"
  },
}
```

I run `ng build`.
Files are generated under `www`, amongs them:

- `index.html`
- `runtime.js`
- `polyfills.js`
- `main.js`
- `styles.css`
- `assets/...`

My app has many routes. For example:

- `/my-project/page1`
- `/my-project/page2`
- `/my-project/page3`

**My question:**

How can I configure `nginx.conf` so the dynamic routes of the application are all handled by `index.html`, but the regular files inside the same `www` folder are served directly?

The `nginx.conf` example you often see online is similar to:

```
server {
    // ...
    root /usr/src/app/www;

    location /my-project {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /my-project/assets {
        alias /usr/src/app/www/assets;
    }
}
```

But when I try that, it seems that even the *regular files* are redirected to `index.html` and HTML is returned!

For example: `http://localhost/my-project/runtime.js` will return the full HTML of `www/index.html` not the javascript from `www/runtime.js`.

What is missing?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Why request of `/my-project/runtime.js` file should render `www/index.html`? What is the point?

Comment: @user973254 On the contrary, I *don't want* `/my-project/runtime.js` to render `www/index.html` but it does it currently!

Comment: @electrotype That's because with your current configuration nginx searching the `/usr/src/app/www/my-project/runtime.js` file to serve `/my-project/runtime.js` request. Do not change `baseHref`, it should be set as it is set right now, as `/my-project/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you do not understand how nginx `root`, `alias` and `try_files` directives actually works. Check the difference between [`root`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [`alias`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)  yourself, and take into attention that the last parameter of the [`try_files`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive in contradiction of all the previous treated as a new URI to re-evaluate. What you should do instead is to use `my_project` as your `outputPath` too. After that, assuming the full path to your application is `/usr/src/app/my_project`, you can use the following configuration:

```
location /my_project/ {
    root /usr/src/app;
    try_files $uri /my_project/index.html;
}
```

This way your app will be available under `http://localhost/my-project/` URL (note the trailing slash). Your global root can be set to any other directory, it won't affect your application. If you want it to be available even if the trailing slash is missing, you can add an additional redirect:

```
location = /my_project {
    return 301 /my_project/;
}
```

If your files structure allows you to place the `my_project` directory under your global web root, things can be even more simple, the above block isn't necessary (as well as the additional `root` directive) since nginx will made the redirect automatically.

If for some reason you can't place your app into the folder named `my_project`, you can use an `alias` directive. However this is better to be avoided because of several [side effects](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) when you are using `alias` and `try_files` directives together. Nevertheless configuration required for an angular app should not face any of those side effects so assuming your project path is `/usr/src/app/www` the following configuration should work:

```
location /my_project/ {
    alias /usr/src/app/www/;
    try_files $uri /my_project/index.html;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution works perfectly. In your example, I think `http://localhost/my-project/` should be `http://localhost/my_project/` ("_" instead of "-"). Or, even better, maybe you should use "-" everywhere since this is what I use in my question.