# Deployed app in Aws not picking up the js and css files

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, devops

I have multiple applications running on my project AWS cloud going through a load balancer, I am adding another application (Angular app) to it, So let's say that someone hits `abc.com` **App1** will respond which is in react, if someone hits `abc.com/register` the **angular app (App2)** will respond to it.
I have created an image with a replacement for the Nginx `default.conf` for Nginx as follows:

**default.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Stage 1

FROM node as build-step

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.*json /app

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

RUN npm run build

# Stage 2

FROM nginx

EXPOSE 80


COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/registration-client /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The main app is `abc.com`.
My app is on `abc.com/register`, I have mapped the same too

Now when I try to access it on `/register`, I get the following errors.

```
GET abc.com/runtime.631649820b9b323c.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
register:13          GET abc.com/polyfills.1072a3be36d7e540.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
register:13          GET abc.com/main.94ecc5179c7eb641.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
register:1 Refused to apply style from abc.com/styles.f26cdcb57409ceba.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

I have made some changes suggested [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56632496/failed-to-load-module-script).

I do feel that my problem is similar to the answer I found.

**One possible explanation for the error:**

You get this behavior when you deploy your app into a subfolder, not directly on your base-URL. The HTML is found when you go to `www.yourbase.com/yoursubfolder/index.html`, but as the angular app fetches other resources from `www.yourbase.com/resource.css` instead of from `www.yourbase.com/yoursubfolder/resource.css` and your webserver probably serves some default page (maybe your `www.yourbase.com/index.html`) the content of your CSS becomes the content of that HTML page. That would explain the error.

**I made changes in my `package.json` accordingly but it didn't work.**
**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run && ng serve --port 3000",
    "build": "npm run && ng build --base-href register",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pretty": "prettier --write \"./**/*.{js,jsx,json,html,css}\""
  }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Assuming your angular router can handler your `/register`-prefixed routes correctly, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72220870/7121513) answer to find out the correct nginx config for such an app.

Comment: My angular app is mapped to `/register` but the app does not have `/register`.  So every time you come to `abc.com/register` it will point to the root of my angular app route.

Comment: I'm not sure it can work that way at all, especially if the angular router uses HTML5 History API (like the react BrowserRouter one). I also think the proper value for the `--bast-href` option should be `/register/`, not the `register`.

Comment: I went with `--base-href=/register/` first, this is just an iteration of the solution.
We have multiple applications running going through the same load balancer. So let's say that someone hits `abc.com` **App1** will respond which is in react, if someone hits `abc.com/register` my angular app will respond to it.

Comment: You are saying that if the load balancer route `abc.com/register` is mapped to the angular app, then the app route that responds to it should be `register`?

Comment: I don't know how that AWS load balancer actually works, maybe it can transform the request URI if being set to do it or maybe not, however I'm sure without being instructed some special way it won't touch the request URI. If your angular app uses the most common [`PathLocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/guide/router#locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles), it will see the route exactly as it being entered at the browser address bar, so if the angular router is involved in any way in the app rendering process, most likely the answer is **Yes**.

Comment: Back to the way your app requests its assets (or speaking more exactly, how the user browser requests them for your app), it depends on `base-href` or `deploy-url` options used to build the app (you can check the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69610410/7121513)). Anyway to make a proper nginx config I suggest you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72220870/7121513) answer carefully again.

Comment: Another question, locally if I run the image, the results are what I want them to be. It only gets messed up when deployed. Any idea why?

Comment: Run locally via `ng serve` and accessing the app directly or run locally via `ng build` and accessing the app through nginx?

Comment: No, I created the image through the dockerfile and made a container locally. I accessed the app inside the container.

Comment: So, I tried everything. Also, looked into the container that is running. I was simply putting my angular apps index.html inside `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder, so it loads that html and resources to it are in the same folder as well. Yet it is not loading them and giving 404 error.

Comment: Return to the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245031/discussion-between-van-wilder-and-ivan-shatsky), you definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: I am in the chat now.